# Send the request to next event handler in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a module which can log some certain params for the request and print them to the page which can be checked online, the page will use the `socket.io` to load the latest logs.

And I want this module can worked as a plugin which means you just call this module, and initialize it, then an extra entry point `/_logger` will be added to you application, once you visit the page, the latest logs will be updated in real-time. So the module have to intercept the requests:

```
function setup(httpServer) {
    //page
    httpServer.on("request", function (request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        if (pathname === '/_logger') {
            fs.readFile(__dirname + '/logger.html', (err, data) => {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                response.write(data);
                response.end();
            });
        }else{
          // how to give up the control for this requset
        }
    });


    var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        //TO BE DONE
        socket.on('event', function (data) { });
        socket.on('disconnect', function () { });
    });
}
module.exports = {
    setup: setup
}
```

Usage:

```
var logger= require("./logger/index");
var server = require('http').createServer();
logger.setup(server);
server.on("request", function(req,res){
  //Normal logic for different application
});
server.listen(3333);
```

Now the problem is that once the requested url is  not `/_logger`, I should release the control of this request.

```
        if (pathname === '/_logger') {
          //take control
        }else{
          // Nothing should be done here, it should go to the next request chain.
        }
```

After read the documents, I can not find the right way to make it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use low-level NodeJS HTTP API. You can compose several handlers into one handler using function composition. Each handler should yield the execution to the next handler, if the `req.url` doesn't matches.

```
var http = require('http');

var handler1 = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('/');
    res.end();  
}

var handler2 = function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('/Hello');
    res.end();  
}

var middleware = compose([wrapHandler('/', handler1),
                         wrapHandler('/hello', handler2)]);

http.createServer(middleware).listen(3000);

function wrapHandler(path, cb) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.url === path) {
            cb(req, res);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    };
}

function notFoundHandler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('No Path found');
    res.end();    
};

// adapted from koa-compose
function compose(middleware) {
    return function (req, res){
        let next = function () {
            notFoundHandler.call(this, req, res);
        };

        let i = middleware.length;
        while (i--) {
            let thisMiddleware = middleware[i];
            let nextMiddleware = next;
            next = function () { 
                thisMiddleware.call(this, req, res, nextMiddleware);
            }
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

In your case, you can write.

```
var loggerHandler = wrapHandler('/_logger', logger.handler);
httpServer.on('request', compose(loggerHandler, handler2, handler3));
```

Comment: I am afraid not, the `logger` module should work as a separate plugin. Which means the `logger` module should be un-invasion.

Comment: @hguser Instead of using `logger.setup(server)` you can export the handler from the logger module as in: `var logH = logger.handler; server.on('request', compose([logH, otherHandler]))`;

Comment: @hguser You can use the `wrapHandler` function to bind simple handlers with a specific path.

Answer (score 1):

`httpServer.on("request", ...)` is just one request listener.  It is under no obligation to process the request if it doesn't need to.  Even if it does nothing, any other request listeners will still get notified of this request.

If there are other request listeners (which you are implying that there are), then you can just do nothing in the request listener you show and the other listeners will also get a shot at the particular request.  This allows you to add your own request listener to a working http server and your listener only has to pay attention to the new route that it wants to support and can just ignore all the other routes and they will get handled by the other listeners that are already in place.

---

Now, there are frameworks built to make this both simpler and to give you more control.  In general, these frameworks use one listener and they provide a means for you to handle the request OR explicitly tell the framework that you have not handled the request and would like other route handlers to have a shot at handling the request.  This is a bit more flexible than just have multiple listeners, all of which will get notified of the same route.

For example, using the Express framework, you can do this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// route handler for / request only when a user=xxx is in the query string
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // if user was included in query parameter
    if (req.query.user) {
        // do something specific when ?user=xxxx is included in the URL
    } else {
        // pass handling to the next request handler in the chain
        next();
    }
});

// route handler for / request that wasn't already handled
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // handle the / route here
});

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: But I can  not assume that all the application which may use the `logger` module are built upon express,connect or something else.

Comment: And, as you mentioned, one listener can do nothing if it does not need to do, in my example, there are two listener added on the `request` event one is the application and the other is the `logger` module so every request will be handled first by the `logger` and then the application, once the requested url is `_logger`, the application handler are still called which will cause the error `write after end`

Comment: @hguser - You didn't fully explain the restrictions you're working in.  I'm just explaining how a real framework passes requests from one handler to the next.  If you don't have access to such a framework, then all you can do is add a listener like you were doing and handle the request if it matches your route and do nothing if it doesn't.  There's no generic way to "hook" into other http server listeners.  That's what request frameworks like Express provide.  The plain http object does not provide that.

Comment: @hguser - The http module, by itself, does not provide a way to skip other server listeners.  You will have to find a different way to hook into the request that is compatible with the application you're trying to patch.  You don't show us that other application so it's hard for us to know how to make something that might be compatible with it.

Comment: `There's no generic way to "hook" into other http server listeners` If so, I got it. I may use the solution provided by `zeronone` to make my own listener chain.

Comment: @hguser - I did think of one possibility.  You might be able to hack the server emitter by overriding `.emit()` and when you see a `request` event getting emitted, you check it there and if you processed it, you don't let the regular `.emit()` get called at all.  If you didn't process it, you let the regular `.emit()` get called so the regular listener gets the event.  This is a hack.

Comment: @hguser - If you don't control the other listeners, how do you make your own listener chain?  I'm not following how that would help you.  If you're trying to make a reusable module for lots of node.js app server people to use, I would start by making your module work as Express middleware.  That's by far the biggest target and the Express framework already supports exactly what you want.  After doing that, you can find out how much of a demand there is for something besides Express (either another framework or generic http).